# How to restrict anyone (root user also) to modify file in Linux

Tags: security, permissions, linux-kernel, filesystems, selinux

I am developing one security base software for Linux platform using C and CPP. I want to restrict all users (even root user) also to modify the file. i.e No one can modify the file.

Modifying means no-one can write to the file, move the file or remove the file etc.

More precisely:

I have a file named as **a.txt** in directory `/home/` and I want to do something to this file so that **no one can write** into this file, **remove** this file or **move** this file.

But can read the file.

I tried `chattr` command:

```
chattr +i /home/a.txt
```

It solved my problem for other users but when I switched to superuser i.e root user into terminal and I fired command:

```
chattr -i /home/a.txt
```

So `/home/a.txt` file become mutable. root user can change file immutable to mutable. So the problem is not solved for root user.

I want to do something to this file, so even root user can't modify this file.

I already ask this question at [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/558978/387776) and [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1198627/1027794) and did not get any answer.

Comment: How is this question differs from your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453714/how-to-set-file-to-immutable-for-all-user-root-user-also-and-no-one-can-modify)? Your previous question was closed on purpose: it is not about **programming**. Why do you ask the same question again?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I already mention in the question that I asked this question of I didn't get answer on Unix&Linux, askUbuntu. And about previous same question, jww and some another member closed my question here so where I can get answer. On another platform (Unix&Linux and askUbuntu) I didin't get answer and you closed question from here. You tell me where I should I ask question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set file to immutable for all user (Root user also) and no one can modify (Root User also)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453714/how-to-set-file-to-immutable-for-all-user-root-user-also-and-no-one-can-modify)

Comment: @Tsyvarev  No one has given answer there my friend.

Comment: Actually, the comment with phrase "Does this answer your question?" followed by a link to the question is **generated automatically** by Stack Overflow when someone votes for close the question as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) or flags it so. Usually the duplicate question is already has an answer (at least one), but when someone repeats his/her question, the older question could be marked as a duplicate for the new one, even if the older one has no answers.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the definition of the root user in Unix systems is that no permission checking is done by the kernel when the user is root (with some [insignificant exceptions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_05)).

So, if you want to prevent root from doing something, you have to write a kernel module that does that. Indeed, most security-related software has kernel components. And this will be harder than you think - root can basically unmount the filesystem and mount it on another machine, or boot with a kernel that doesn't include your module.

There are already a few security-related kernel modules that you can look into: [SELinux](http://blog.siphos.be/2015/07/restricting-even-root-access-to-a-folder/), [AppArmor](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apparmor.html) etc. (also [Tomoyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomoyo) and [Smack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smack_(software)), but they don't seem helpful in this case). Depending on your requirement, they might be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Put your app in an appliance with disk encryption.